Ubuntu 24 Freezes After Enabling Real-Time Kernel and NVIDIA Driver Issues
I recently installed Ubuntu 24 and enabled Ubuntu Pro using the free subscription. After that, I enabled the real-time kernel using the appropriate commands. However, after enabling the real-time kernel, my system freezes shortly after startup.
I tried running
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
to resolve the issue, but the problem persists. I also attempted to update the NVIDIA drivers using:
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
However, I encountered errors during the process, which seem to indicate that the NVIDIA drivers are not compatible with the real-time kernel.
Is there a way to resolve the compatibility issue between the NVIDIA drivers and the real-time kernel? Alternatively, how can I revert to a non-real-time kernel to regain system stability?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
